# Expected ':' before '.' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the Expected ':' before '.' token error with this piece of code: 
`[SecondViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];`

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define AS(A,B)    [(A) stringByAppendingString:(B)]

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
```

.m:

```
[SecondViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Any hints ?

And if your wondering i am trying to Refresh the view

Comment: can you post 3-4, or even more, lines that are preceding this line? and the .h where SecondViewController is declared?

Comment: Sorry how do i declare secondviewcontroller ? sorry im new to this

Comment: Please post the full `.h` and `.m` files. Otherwise it is impossible to see what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Im just trying to refresh the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to access the Class object for your controller and not an instance object (which is what view property is defined on). Additionally setNeedsDisplay: needs a boolean parameter.

So either use this syntax if it's called from within the view controller:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Or this syntax if it's from somewhere else:

```
SecondViewController *myController;
...
[myController.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see what `SecondViewController` is.
So I can only answer: [The class reference for NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) states that `setNeedsDisplay:` ask for a `BOOL` argument followed after the colon.

Comment: it is a

.h
.m
.xib

but im calling this from the .m

Comment: This is obviously an iOS project, so in this context `UIView` is different from `NSView`. This means that it is `[NSView setNeedsDisplay:YES]` but `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]`. Notice that UIView's implementation **does not take a boolean**. BTW, I still do not know why you ever wanted to pass something different than `YES` to the function when you want to refresh the view.

Comment: Sry, but the context was not given when the posting appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check for a missing header file, is SecondViewController defined in this context?

Answer (score 0):

@user393273: Can you also elaborate? It's hard to help with only one line of code to go on. For instance, can you give us the `SecondViewController` header file - are you sure you're subclassing anything, for instance UIViewController? You should have something like `@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController` in the header. And please give us the method in which you're calling the above line. Also, what are you setting the property `needsDisplay` to?

Comment: Have you tried `[SecondViewController.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];` as per JJD's answer?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is from SecondViewController.